# How to use clang 5 with qt in qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've configured my locally installed version of clang 5.

[image]

and set up a kit with it

[image]

but when I do a build with it:

[image]

it's clearly still using the system compiler for qmake, which causes a bunch of errors because my code requires C++17 support:

[image]

How do I set what compiler qmake is using?

Thank you.

Comment: While the answer below worked, the final solution I ended up going with was moving the entire build to cmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in your pro file, directly:

```
QMAKE_CC = /path/to/the/c/compiler
QMAKE_CXX = /path/to/the/c++/compiler
```

but you'd be better specify the correct *Qt mkspec* in your kit, which could be something like *linux-clang*. Check the *mkspecs* directory, see if in some of its subdirectories there is the right *qmake.conf* already, if not you can make a new subdirectory in *mkspecs* and a new configuration file inside it. The *mkspecs* directory should be in the path given by the terminal command

```
qmake -query QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA
```

Hope it helped.